# Symfony 5 - How to inject bundle configuration file in service or controller

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony5

I'm actually learning how SF5 works and I have a question regarding config file injection into service or controller.

I have created an "AuthenticationBundle". Then in config/packages/authentication.yaml, I have put the configuration required for the module.

```
authentication:
   login : 1234
   password : 5678
```

I also created Configuration (explaining config via TreeBuilder) and Extension files inside DepedencyInjection repository of the bundle.

From there, inside load function, I am able to see the content of my configuration file.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html

But now, how can I inject it into Controller or Service ? The documentation is not enough clear on this point (at least for a new SF user point of view).

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I reply to myself.

In the Extension file (AuthenticationExtension in my case), I set a new parameter to the service container this way :

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) : void
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();

    // merge config
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    // define the name of the key to be injected in controller or service
    $container->setParameter('authentication', $config);
}
```

Then, in services.yaml file, I was able to pass my variable to the controller.

```
App\AuthenticationBundle\Controller\AuthenticationController :
    arguments:
        $authenticationConfig: '%authentication%' # define the name of the parameter that will be injected into the controller
```

After that, I just had to retrieve them in controller constructor.

```
public function __construct(array $authenticationConfig)
{
    $this->authenticationConfig = $authenticationConfig;
}
```

Hope this can help somebody else.

If some Syfmony expert read my post, feel free to tell me if I'm doing things wrong.

Comment: [@Benjamin Ghenne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1809441), your solution works, but I'm curious: Did you ever manage to define your service inside of the bundle (e.g. loaded with the `XmlFileLoader`) and not in the global `services.yaml`? I couldn't get it done by following the [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html). The config array was intact in the extension class. But in the service it was always empty.